# Python how do get the value a thread?

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

Program that determines whether changing the current directory using os.chdir in one thread changes the current directory for a thread that already existed before the call to os.chdir
My question is how do I get the value of a live thread?

```
import threading
import time
import os
class MyThread(threading.Thread):
def __init__(self, *args, **kw):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self, *args, **kw)
    self.sleeptime = 2
def run(self):        
    for i in range(self.sleeptime):
        for j in range(500000):
            k = j*j
        print(self.name, "finished pass", i)
    print(self.name, "finished after", self.sleeptime, "seconds")

bgthreads = threading.active_count()
threadOne = os.chdir("V:\\workspace\\Python4_Homework10")
threadTwo = os.chdir("V:\\workspace")
threadThree = os.chdir("V:")
tt = [MyThread(threadOne), MyThread(threadTwo), MyThread(threadThree)]
for t in tt:    
   t.start()

print("Threads started")
while threading.active_count() > bgthreads:
    time.sleep(2)
    print("tick")
```

Comment: `threadTwo = os.chdir("V:\\workspace")` sets `threadTwo` to be the output of `os.chdir("V:\\workspace")`, so you call `os.chdir()` when setting the variable. I don't think that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: The current working directory is global process state.  Not per thread.

Comment: What I need is the value of the thread to verify that changing the directory in one thread dose or not effect the other threads.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit crude, but this might get your job done.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import os
import threading

def threadReporter(i,name):
    if name == 'Thread-changer': # crude, but gets the job done for this
        os.chdir('/tmp')
    print("{0} reports current pwd is: {1}".format(name,os.getcwd()))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # create pre-chdir and changer Thread
    t_pre = threading.Thread(target=threadReporter, args=(1,'Thread-pre'))
    t_changer = threading.Thread(target=threadReporter, args=(2,'Thread-changer'))

    # start changer thread
    t_changer.start()
    # wait for it to finish
    t_changer.join()

    # start the thread that was created before the os.chdir() call
    t_pre.start()

    # create a thread after the os.chdir call and start it
    t_post = threading.Thread(target=threadReporter, args=(3,'Thread-post'))
    t_post.start()
```

As gps already pointed out above, the current working directory is process-global and not separate for each thread that may be spawned/running. Therefore the report of the current working directory from the program above is equal for each thread that runs, no matter when the thread was created. After an os.chdir(), that new working directory is set for all threads.